# set marker to scale with y axis (with limits)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to scale my marker points with my y-axis values in matplotlib. I thought i could use "counts" from pandas to count the instances of each y-axis value, then set that range to the size values of my scatterplot, but the scale is all messed up and the marker points become huge (the range of y-axis values range from 1 to 17,000). What is a good way to scale this number back to something between 1 and 10?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel("dataset.xlsx")

scale_range = pd.value_counts(data["y_axis"].values, sort = True))

plt.scatter(data["x_axis"], data["y_axis"], s = scale_range)
plt.axis([0, 120, 0, 1])

plt.show('dataset_out.png')
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Divide by 1700?

Comment: lol yeah i gues i could find some percent to make the values in line to the scale i want. I was looking for a more "pythonic" way of doing it, Thanks though!

Comment: I think that's a pretty "pythonic" method. It's straightforward at least. Another thing you might want to consider is `size` sets the area and not the diameter.

Comment: I wonder why that approach works at all. `value_counts` will produce a series of unique elements of its argument, which are generally less than the number of total elements. So either each value occurs exactly once, then you get all `1` in `scale_range`, or `scale_range` does not even have as many elements as `x_axis`, which might throw an error, or at least will give an incorrect plot. In that sense, why not use the y_axis values themselves? `plt.scatter(data["x_axis"], data["y_axis"], s = data["y_axis"]+10)`?

Comment: I tried your method and it doesnt scale at all. Im not really sure why, your method seems like a fine idea.

Comment: I was actually curious how this worked for you as well, but I assumed you didn't include some pertinent info. Regardless, scaling down your values for `s` between 1 and 10 by dividing by "max value"/10 should work fine.

Comment: Well, it's about all one can say without runnable code. Good luck still.